# SmsManager + SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have made an application where i save some numbers inside a SQLiteDatabase.

My question is: Can i read this Database from inside SmsManager?

For example: I would like to make some comparisons inside sendTextMessage() with the values which are saved inside this Database. Can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to doing something *inside* `sendTextMessage()` is to extend the `SmsManager` class and override `sendTextMessage()`. But it might be easier to perform your comparisons before calling `sendTextMessage()`.

Comment: where can i perform these Comparisons ? I would like any app which use SmsManager to make these comparisons?

Comment: "any app which use SmsManager" Sorry, you cannot change how the SmsManager works for _all_ apps without changing the OS itself.

Comment: If i want to change the OS how can i could success these actions?

Comment: This is unrealistic. Every one that wants to use your app must install a new OS...

Comment: I want to do this for myself to extract some conclusions for my thesis and i am new in this area.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you need to download the source code for Android (~6GB), change a few lines, compile it and forcibly install it on your device.  It is _far_ easier to collect data by creating an SMS app yourself or download the source code for the default SMS app and change it; if this is an option.

Comment: I have already done this. So my question is if i can use inside SmsManager a function to get results from a SLiteDatabase

Comment: As I said: "you cannot change how the SmsManager works for _all_ apps without changing the OS itself." If you want write code _inside_ SmsManager for _your_ app "extend the SmsManager class and override sendTextMessage()".